# Select distinct from two column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My database like this: table name: messages

```
| receive | transmit |
---------------------
|   1    |  5    |
|   1    |  6    |
|   1    |  3    |
|   3    |  1    |
|   4    |  1    |
|   2    |  3    |
|   4    |  6    |
|   7    |  9    |
```

And i am trying to get all unique id's from each table. So my answer must be 1, 3, 4, 5, 6.

if i use     `SELECT DISTINCT receive FROM messages ;` i will get 1, 3 ,4

if i use     `SELECT DISTINCT transmit FROM messages ;` i will get 1, 3 ,5, 6

how do i get 1, 3, 4, 5, 6?

Comment: yikes - fr_om? That's some odd column naming (as is to). If you're specifying a range, say it's a range. If you're specifying a foreign key to another table, specify what that ID is.

Comment: So, are the tables `from` and `to`, or the columns?. Your wording seems to say columns, but the query shows tables

Comment: actually i use `from` but i thought it may confused people so i wrote like this.

Comment: Sidenote: `from` and `to` are MySQL reserved words. Try not using those or adjust accordingly. Use backticks.

Comment: Your second question is that....another question

Comment: yes i use backticks but i dont know how to show backticks in stackoverflow beacuse when i do that it marks as a code script.

Comment: @GorkemYontem Are `from` and `to` tables or columns?

Comment: @Lamak should i open a new question? Sorry but i have just started using stackoverflow maybe you can teach me something instead of just judging.

Comment: GorkemYontem yes, @Lamak is suggesting you write another question for that. And he wasn't judging, he was merely pointing that you shouldn't put 2 questions in one. But what's wrong with judging anyway? This question is pretty low on quality. Names like "from" and "to" - which later revealed not be the real names, confusion about what a table or a column is (the question is still unclear whether you have 1 or 2 tables!) I suggest you write more carefully the next question. And wear a thick skin next time, when you publicize to the entire Internet your thoughts, expect judgement.

Comment: @ypercube thank you for your comment. i am always open to this kind of comments. It make sense. Not like "Your second question is that....another question". yes of course my second question was another question. thats why i said MY SECOND QUESTION at the first place. Lamaks comment doesn't contain anything except judging so this is useless for me.. Actually i got this database from php dolphin script. That guy wrote thousand of code and build a fully equipped social networking website, but he use from and to as a name of columns. i didnt know it may cause that kind of mess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default for `UNION` is `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT "from" FROM tableX 
UNION
SELECT "to" FROM tableX;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `"from"` mean the string literal `from`, rather than the column name?

Comment: Depends on ANSI QUOTES setting.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `fr_om` FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT `to` FROM `table` WHERE `to` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `fr_om` FROM table)
```

*Updated* :  you can just use [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) to remove the duplicates from your result set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `fr_om` FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT `to` FROM `table`
```